# How do you multiply transition probability matrixes?

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains

Say I'm trying to find $P^{2}$ and I just need to multiply the initial state (this is the middle row) \begin{bmatrix}0.25&0.5&0.25\end{bmatrix} by the transition probability matrix

\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}

The answer should be \begin{bmatrix}0.32&0.4425&0.2375\end{bmatrix}

I just can't figure out what exactly I'm supposed to be multiplying that would give me that answer.

edit: The solution I was given lists the answer as that first intitial state/line vector times the whole matrix, and the answer is as I listed.  Here is the full question, but its just how to go from one step to another that I can't figure out:

Suppose that the offspring’s
choice of post-secondary education
(university/college/trade) is dependent on the highest level of education
received by their parents. If one parent went to university, there is a 60%
chance that the offspring
will attend university, 25% chance that they will
attend college. If one parent went to college, there is a 50% chance they
will attend college as well, and 25% chance they will enter a trade. If one
parent works in a trade, there is a 52% chance that they will attend
college, and 30% chance they will enter a trade.
If a child currently has one parent who chose to go to college, what are
the chances that the child’s future child will also attend college?

Comment: What's the probability distribution after one step? What is it after two steps?

Comment: Well, if $$P=\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}$$ then $$P^2=\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}$$ Is this your question? What has the line vector in your question got to do with it?

Comment: @Pieter21 After one step is the full matrix I listed, after two steps is what I'm trying to figure out afaik.

Comment: @Did No, it's not.  I posted the full question in the original post.  The solution I was given for the question is that line vector times the probability matrix which results in the answer I listed.  Multiplying them together to get that answer is something I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: The trouble is that your "Say I'm trying to find $P^{2}$" and your "I just need to multiply the initial state (...) by the transition probability matrix" are not related. The first part is answered in my first comment, the second part seems to ask how to multiply a line vector of size $1\times3$ by a square matrix of size $3\times3$. Is this last question what you are really asking?

Comment: After the edit, it appears you are asked for the value of $c$ in the identity $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&0.52&0.3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&0.52&0.3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u&c&t\end{bmatrix}$$ Can you do that? To shorten your computations, you might want to (prove and) use the fact that $$c=
\begin{bmatrix}0.25&0.5&0.25\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0.25\\0.5\\0.52\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting muddled in your notation.

Usually the $n$th state is given by $x^{(n)}$ and the transition matrix is given by $P$.

You will have started with $x^{(0)}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\ \end{bmatrix}$

You then worked out $x^{(1)}=x^{(0)}P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix}0.25&0.5&0.25\ \end{bmatrix}$

If you don't really understand matrix multiplication then you won't understand how you got there, so I will try to explain.

To get the first element of $x^{(1)}$ you multiply the elements of the first column of the matrix by the corresponding elements of $x^{(0)}$ and add them together:

$0.6 \times 0 + 0.25 \times 1  + 0.18 \times 0 = 0.25$

$0.25 \times 0 + 0.5 \times 1  + 0.52 \times 0 = 0.5$

$0.15 \times 0 + 0.25 \times 1  + 0.3 \times 0 = 0.25$

What you want next is not $P^2$ - that would be the $3 \times 3$ matrix representing the transition over two generations.

Instead you want $x^{(2)}=x^{(1)}P$

$x^{(2)}=\begin{bmatrix}0.25&0.5&0.25\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.25&0.15\\0.25&0.5&0.25\\0.18&.52&.3\end{bmatrix}$

Now follow the same procedure as before. I'll do the first element for you:

$0.6 \times 0.25 + 0.25 \times 0.5  + 0.18 \times 0.25 = 0.32$

Comment: Great explanation!  The middle row of the x(1) should be 0.25×0+0.5×1+0.52×0 = 0.5 vs 0.52 ...right?

Comment: @shao.lo  Yes: thank you. I have edited it now.